# when using tensor flow i am getting error TypeError

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I am new to neural networks. I am getting error on the below line in my code

`net = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, len(train_x[0])])`

Below is the error , I am getting"

```
TypeError: object of type 'numpy.float64' has no len()
```

I tried below syntax and it still give me an error

`net = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, len(train_x)])`

The error that I got:

`ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (8,) for Tensor 'InputData/X:0', which has shape '(?, 19579)'`

Can you please help suggest what should I do?

Also, below is the complete syntax, if required

```
import numpy as np # linear algebra
import pandas as pd # data processing, CSV file I/O (e.g. pd.read_csv)


# Input data files are available in the "../input/" directory.
# Any results you write to the current directory are saved as output.
#from subprocess import check_output
#print(check_output(["ls", "../input"]).decode("utf8"))


train = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/gunjit.bedi/Desktop/Tensor Flow/input/train.csv')
print(train.head())

import nltk as nl
train['tokens'] = [nl.word_tokenize(sentences) for sentences in train.text]
words = []
for item in train.tokens:
    words.extend(item)

stemmer = nl.stem.lancaster.LancasterStemmer()
words = [stemmer.stem(word) for word in words]


filtered_words = [word for word in words if word not in nl.corpus.stopwords.words('english')]



import gensim
# let X be a list of tokenized texts (i.e. list of lists of tokens)
model = gensim.models.Word2Vec(filtered_words, size=100)
w2v = dict(zip(model.wv.index2word, model.wv.syn0))

print(w2v['h'])

training = []
for index, item in train.iterrows():
    vec = np.zeros(100)
    token_words = [stemmer.stem(word) for word in item['tokens']]
    token_words = [word for word in token_words if word not in nl.corpus.stopwords.words('english')]
    for w in token_words:
        if w in w2v:
            vec += w2v[w]
    norm = np.linalg.norm(vec)
    if norm != 0:
        vec /= np.linalg.norm(vec)

    training.append(vec)

training_new = np.array(training)

from numpy import array

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

# integer encode
label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
integer_encoded = label_encoder.fit_transform(training_new[:,1])

# binary encode
onehot_encoder = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)
integer_encoded = integer_encoded.reshape(len(integer_encoded), 1)
onehot_encoded = onehot_encoder.fit_transform(integer_encoded)

train_y = onehot_encoded

train_x = list(training_new[:,0])

print(len(train_x))
print(type(train_x))

import tensorflow as tf
import tflearn

# reset underlying graph data
tf.reset_default_graph()
# Build neural network
net = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, len(train_x[0])])
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 8)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 8)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, len(train_y), activation='softmax')
net = tflearn.regression(net)

# Define model and setup tensorboard
model = tflearn.DNN(net, tensorboard_dir='tflearn_logs')
# Start training (apply gradient descent algorithm)
model.fit(train_x, train_y, n_epoch=10, batch_size=8, show_metric=True)
model.save('model.tflearn')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the above issue, the error seemed to in the below code

```
training = []
for index, item in train.iterrows():
    vec = np.zeros(100)
    token_words = [stemmer.stem(word) for word in item['tokens']]
    token_words = [word for word in token_words if word not in nl.corpus.stopwords.words('english')]
    for w in token_words:
        if w in w2v:
            vec += w2v[w]
    norm = np.linalg.norm(vec)
    if norm != 0:
        vec /= np.linalg.norm(vec)

    training.append(vec)
```

I changed it to below : Check the last line of code

```
training = []
for index, item in train.iterrows():
    vec = np.zeros(100)
    token_words = [stemmer.stem(word) for word in item['tokens']]
    token_words = [word for word in token_words if word not in nl.corpus.stopwords.words('english')]
    for w in token_words:
        if w in w2v:
            vec += w2v[w]
    norm = np.linalg.norm(vec)
    if norm != 0:
        vec /= np.linalg.norm(vec)
    training.append([vec,item['author']])
```

The error was because the 'author' column was not appended.
If the tensorflow experts can confirm if my solution is indeed correct that will be great.

Answer (score 0):

`len()` tells you the length of the array you have passed to it.

`train_x[0]` gets you the *first* element of the `train_x` array, which does not have any length property hence the error message.

```
TypeError: object of type 'numpy.float64' has no len()
```

This is why when you remove `[0]` you do not get an error from `len(train_x)`.

I'm not familiar with Tensor Flow so can't comment further but that should hopefully explain the source of your error.

Comment: Hi, I checked again, and after removing the [0], I am still getting an error. I have updated my post